# How to I use map() to add a grouped index to a column of data frames?

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have data which has two measurements of on two different groups with a number of samples for each. I simple version with 6 samples each looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(group = c(rep("group_A", 12), rep("group_B", 12)),
         sample = rep(1:6, 4),
         measurement = rep(c(rep("meas_A", 6), rep("meas_B", 6)), 2), 
         value = round(runif(24, min = 0, max = 60)))
```

but because the measurements have been repeated in different conditions it is actually a series of similar data frames represented in a list:

```
df2 <- bind_rows(df,df,df,df) %>% 
  mutate(condition = c(rep("One", 24), rep("Two", 24), 
                       rep("Three", 24), rep("Four", 24))) %>% 
  unite(group_meas, group, measurement) %>% 
  nest(-condition)
```

Ultimately I'd like to reshape each data frame into a wide format so that vectors of the two measurements for each group can be easily extracted from single columns for statistical comparison. For example:

```
df %>% unite(group_meas, group, measurement) 
  %>%  spread(group_meas, value)
```

which can be mapped down the list like so:

```
df2 %>% mutate(data = map(data, ~spread(.x, group_meas, value)))
```

**My problem arises when a sample has been measured more than once** and then `spread()` does not work because there are

> Duplicate identifiers for rows

I figure the best way around this is to add a new index column grouped on the combined group/measurement and this will provide unique row identifiers. This works for a single data frame.

```
df %>% unite(group_meas, group, measurement) %>% 
  group_by(group_meas) %>% 
  mutate(gr_m_index = row_number())
```

However I cannot scale it to map down a list.

```
df2 %>% mutate(data = map(data, ~  group_by(.x, group_meas) %>% 
                            mutate(gr_m_index = row_number())))
```

I think this must be a `tidyeval` thing as I get the following error suggesting it is looking in the wrong place.

> Evaluation error: Column `gr_m_index` must be length 24 (the number of
>   rows) or one, not 4.

How to I use `map()` to add a grouped index to a column of data frames?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, based on the error message, `row_number()` was returning `c(1, 2, 3, 4)`. This is because the number of rows was counted based on `df2`, rather than the nested data frames.

Either approach below should work:

**Approach 1**. Define all the transformations to be mapped as a standalone function.

```
index_spread <- function(data){
  return(data %>% 
           group_by(group_meas) %>% 
           mutate(gr_m_index = row_number()) %>%
           spread(group_meas, value))
}

df2 %>% mutate(data = map(data, index_spread)) %>% unnest()

# A tibble: 24 x 7
   condition sample gr_m_index group_A_meas_A group_A_meas_B group_B_meas_A group_B_meas_B
       <chr>  <int>      <int>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
 1       One      1          1             12             43             39             52
 2       One      2          2             11             60              8             20
 3       One      3          3             41             23             16             29
 4       One      4          4             23             47             23             36
 5       One      5          5             46             56              1             30
 6       One      6          6             30             13             23             11
 7       Two      1          1             12             43             39             52
 8       Two      2          2             11             60              8             20
 9       Two      3          3             41             23             16             29
10       Two      4          4             23             47             23             36
# ... with 14 more rows
```

**Approach 2**. Perform the transformations on `df2$data`, & assign the list of transformed data frames back to the original.

```
df2$data <- map(df2$data, ~group_by(.x, group_meas) %>% 
                  mutate(gr_m_index = row_number()) %>%
                  spread(group_meas, value))
df2 %>% unnest()

# (same output as above)
```